# SonarQube 5.1.2 with Postgres 9.2 DB

Tags: maven, sonarqube, postgresql-9.2

I have installed SonarQube with Postgres db but I have a problem with this configuration. My sonar analyses my application code through Jenkins build using sonar-maven-plugin but it keeps failing on

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project p1-sgz: Fail to execute request [code=400, url=http ://xxxxxxxx:9003/batch/project?key=xx.xxx.xxxxx.xx%3Axx-xxx%3Axxx-xx&amp;preview=false]: Fail to download [http : // xxxxxxxx : 9003 /batch/project?key=xx.xxx.xxxxx.xx%3Axx-xxx%3Axxx-xx&amp;preview=false]. Response code: 400 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project p1-sgz: Fail to execute request [code=400, url=http : // xxxxxxxx : 9003 /batch/project?key=xx.xxx.xxxxx.xx%3Axx-xxx%3Axxx-xx&amp;preview=false]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to execute request [code=400, url=http :// xxxxxxxx:9003 / batch/project?key=xx.xxx.xxxxx.xx%3Axx-xxx%3Axxx-xx&amp;preview=false]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

above link opened in browser displays:

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"Fail to parse date: 2015-05-20 16:37:23+02"}]}
```

It looks like sonar adds +02 timezone to date and it can't be parsed. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: any stacktrace or error log in sonar.log?

Comment: No stack trace or error in sonar.log even if i switched logging to debug.

Comment: what is the command you use to build the project with jenkins ?

Comment: sonar is triggered by jenkins in post build action, command is mvn clean install -Psome_profiles